# Run FTP application server on NAS or on server connected to NAS?

Tags: linux, ftp, synology

We have 2 main physical servers:

Synology NAS for bulk file storage.
Dell ESXi for applications and processing.

We have an outside source that needs to upload files via FTPS for one of our application server to process.

Is it best practice to run an FTP server in Linux on top of ESXi to share the NAS or should we run a FTP server directly on the NAS? Both have adequate file permissions for our users so the main concern is security.

Comment: neither, either, both? run it in a container. https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp

Comment: @JacobEvans how can I monitor that container with Fail2Ban?

Comment: https://www.the-lazy-dev.com/en/install-fail2ban-with-docker/